# System.import comes from JavaScript or is specific to angular 2

Tags: angular

I am looking at the Hello World quick start angular 2 app as given below.

**Question**

In the Hello World quick start angular 2 app, is the `System.import` a JavaScript statement/construct or a function specific to angular 2?

If it's part of JavaScript, then it needs no special library for it to work else it would need some special library. I am curious what library supplies this functionality.

**Hello World angualr 2 app code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="/src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('/src/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It comes from systemjs in this case

Comment: it's from SystemJS: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Comment: it comes from systemJS, which is no longer the path Angular takes, you should consider using the angular CLI (which uses webpack) in new angular 4 projects

Comment: Thanks to all. Please post your answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @Stavm, so if we use webpack  then webpack will have it's own version of System.import?

Comment: Also, it seems systemjs is an independent library from angular framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.import()` was first considered for a proposal to be a native API for dynamically loading ESM modules. Because of that it was adopted by both SystemJS and Webpack and were used to load modules dynamically during runtime. However, the eventual spec and implementation define `import()` API in a browser (already implemented by Chrome). The newest v3.x of Webpack deprecated `System.import()` and now recognizes `import()`. SystemJS also deprecated `System.import` and now recognizes `SystemJS.import()`. In the case of `quick start angular 2 app` `System.import()` is an old API for `SystemJS`.

Comment: is systemjs something that angular team came up with or its an independent library?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard, does that mean that `System` is now deprecated as a JavaScript global variable? Or its just deprecated for use in the current version of Webpack?

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not following the topic nowadays, you probably should ask a separate question